# PasswordDeriveBytes(.net 2.0) for iPhone

Tags: .net, iphone, objective-c, cryptography, salt

I want to use PasswordDeriveBytes(RSA PBKDF1) of .NET 2.0 within iPhone. How could i achieve the same exact implementation? Are there any methods or libraries for it? I especially want it for using a salt.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MS implementation is not totally following the PKCS#5 specification the easiest way would be to convert Mono (C#) source code into Objective C. That will get you very close to MS implementation (everything except a very bad bug :-). In any case I suggest you stick to the specification (don't get more bytes that what it's designed to provide).

https://raw.github.com/mono/mono/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography/PasswordDeriveBytes.cs

Comment: Out of interest - what's the bug? (if only so I can route it to the owner of that class)

Comment: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=316364
https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=372893
Note that this bug was already reported to Microsoft - but I can't recall its conclusion (and never see Mono's tests fails in later versions)

Comment: Hmm wonder if that got fixed in .NET 4.0. Will raise it anyway :)